# Extract year from date string in this format Dec-06, Jan-90, Feb-76 etc in R

Tags: r, date

I have a data frame in R. It has a column containing dates in this format Dec-06, Jan-90, Feb-76 etc. They are strings. How can I extract year section of it in this format: 2006, 1990, 1976 etc? I want to discard month segment and treat it as distance on year portion of it and treat this column as continuous variable for my logistic regression.

I tried several Date format package provided in R like POSIX, lubridate etc but was not able to extract.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
format(as.Date(gsub(".*-","","Dec-06"), format = "%y"), "%Y")
#[1] "2006"
```

OR

```
library(lubridate)
format(myd(paste("Dec-06","-01",sep="")), "%Y")
#[1] "2006"
```

Comment: format(myd(paste("Dec-06","-01",sep="")), "%Y") worked. Not the earlier one. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

We convert the string into a `Date` class and then extract only the year from it.

```
format(as.Date(paste0("01-", x), "%d-%b-%y"), "%Y")

#[1] "2006" "1990" "1976"
```

**data**

```
x <- c("Dec-06", "Jan-90", "Feb-76 ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `lubridate` , it is easy, year function is a part of lubridate:

```
library(lubridate)
dat <- data.frame(x=c("Mar-06","Jan-90","May-76"))
dat$date <- as.POSIXlt(paste0("01-",tolower(dat$x)),format="%d-%b-%y",origin="1970-01-01")
dat$year <- year(dat$date)
```

**Answer:**

```
> dat
       x       date year
1 Mar-06 2006-03-01 2006
2 Jan-90 1990-01-01 1990
3 May-76 1976-05-01 1976
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option with `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
data.table::year(as.yearmon("Dec-06", "%b-%y"))
#[1] 2006
```

Or as @G.Grothendieck mentioned, `as.integer` returns the `year`

```
as.integer(as.yearmon("Dec-06", "%b-%y"))
#[1] 2006
```

Comment: It's unclear where `year` came from but you could use `as.integer` in its place to avoid further dependencies.